# How to prevent PrimeFaces poll from clearing FacesMessages?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, polling

I'm using PrimeFaces poll component to refresh some content.

```
<h:form id="formBsvtt">
  <p:messages autoUpdate="true" showDetail="false" />
  <p:outputPanel id="panelOut" layout="block">
    ...
    ... content to refresh
    ...
  </p:outputPanel>
  <p:panelGrid id="panelIn" layout="block">
    ...
    ... various input components with validation
    ...
  </p:panelGrid>
  <p:poll widgetVar="poll1" autoStart="true" global="false" interval="15" 
    partialSubmit="true" process="@this" update="panelOut"
    listener="#{myBean.myListener}">
  </p:poll>
</h:form>
```

As you can see I'm using messages with autoUpdate=true. My Problem is: In case of validation errors FacesMessages will be shown, but disappear not later than 15 seconds.

***Is it possible to prevent poll from clearing FacesMessages without setting messages autoUpdate=false?***

My web application is much bigger as code snippet specified above and my intention is not  updating messages manually in each possible case!

Comment: What is the criteria you are following for updating the messages? I think there's no way of preveting `p:poll` from updating `p:messages`. I thought the `process` attribute would do the trick, but it seems it's not the case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### PrimeFaces 2.x/3.x

This is not natively possible, so a trick is needed. In the `rendered` attribute of `<p:messages>`, check if `<p:poll>` was been triggered and if so, then return `false`. This way JSF thinks there's no auto-updatable messages component in the component tree during rendering and will therefore ignore it.

If the `<p:poll>` is triggered, then its client ID appears as `javax.faces.source` request parameter. So, this should do:

```
<p:messages ... rendered="#{param['javax.faces.source'] ne poll.clientId}" />
...
<p:poll binding="#{poll}" ... />
```

*(note: no additional bean properties needed)*

#### PrimeFaces 4.x+

All PrimeFaces command components got a new `ignoreAutoUpdate` attribute which you could set to `false` to ignore all `autoUpdate="true"` components in the ajax update.

```
<p:poll ... ignoreAutoUpdate="true" />
```

Comment: You're welcome. Thank you for asking a question which isn't asked here before :)

Answer (score 9):

For folks using Primefaces 4.0 and above, the Primefaces team have added an attribute to their ajax aware components to skip triggering components with autoUpdate set to true. So your poll would be

```
<p:poll ignoreAutoUpdate="true" .../>
```

See also their blog post about it: http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2836