# p:remoteCommand and p:messages with autoUpdate="true" clears messages

Tags: jsf, primefaces, remotecommand

```
<p:messages id="lockMessage"
            for="lockMessage"
            redisplay="false"
            showDetail="true"
            autoUpdate="true"
            closable="true"/>

<h:form id="form">
    <p:remoteCommand name="updateTable" update="dataTable" process="@this"/>

    <p:commandButton oncomplete="if(args &amp;&amp;!args.validationFailed) {updateTable();}"
                     actionListener="#{bean.action}"
                     value="Save"/>

    <p:dataTable id="dataTable"/>
</h:form>
```

The bean :

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Bean() {}

    public void action() {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        // This is needed somewhere.

        Collection<String> renderIds = facesContext.getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds();
        renderIds.clear();
        renderIds.add("lockMessage");

        // Render the message using some conditional check.

        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        message.setSummary("Summary");
        message.setDetail("Message");
        facesContext.addMessage("lockMessage", message);
    }
}
```

The message appears for a very short while and soon vanishes into thin air, when the given `<p:commandButton>` is clicked.

The message is displayed as usual, if `oncomplete="if(args &amp;&amp;!args.validationFailed) {updateTable();}"` is removed from the `<p:commandButton>`.

Omitting the `<p:remoteCommand>` or setting the `autoUpdate` attribute associated with the `<p:messages>` to `false` is not possible for other certain reasons.

What is to be done for the message to display normally, when the given `<p:commandButton>` is pressed?

Comment: The messages *are* displayed normally, but since you immediately do another ajax call, the messages are updated again and since they are not kind of 'sticky', they disappear. Have your tried adding `ignoreAutoUpdate="true"` to the `<p:remoteCommand />`?

Comment: Effectively, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298913/how-to-prevent-primefaces-poll-from-clearing-facesmessages) is a duplicate

Comment: O/T: Does a remote command without actually calling something on the server 'work'/'do something'? Or did you remove  it for brevity?

Comment: @Kukeltje: that's indeed the answer :)

Comment: Kindly mark it as duplicate and/or add an answer.

Comment: I'll generalize the other Q/A a little and mark it as a duplicate. Reputation points are not important ;-)